# Alternative to returning javascript tag in Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

One ajax request in my code returns some html within which certain elements need custom event handling, like this:

```
<div>
 <!--some html-->
 <button id='specialbutton'></button>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $("#specialbutton").click(function(e){
   //some special handing of html above
});
</script>
```

I understand javascript returned from ajax request are [not executed automatically](http://technify.me/user-experience/javascript/executing-javascript-in-an-ajax-response/), and using eval() to execute return js is considered insecure and generally bad practice. But the code I need to execute here is just local to the html snippet returned (in a Django template), including it in the boilerplate html that sends ajax request seems to violate the rule of seperation. Should I add attribute like 'data-role="specialbutton"' to the element, and globally use jQuery.live() to attach handlers, or what?

What is the best practice here?  Any good advice?

Comment: use http://api.jquery.com/on/ to listen to events on the container of where you are loading the ajax content into

Comment: This is a tough situation, the most consistent way to do it where it will always work would be to bind the event in the success callback. That of course breaks apart the separation. I'd suggest having the additional js in an external script and requesting it in the success.

Comment: could also place the JS in a file, then also return a `<script src="..."></script>` tag in the response, or modify the response like `{content:'html',scripts:['script1.js']}` and use `$.getScript()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some pub/subbing so that the event is only triggered when there is a successful ajax request like so:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function( data ) {
      $(document).trigger('some/special/event');
    }
})

$(document).on( 'some/special/event', function() {
    $("#specialbutton").on( 'click', function(e){
         //some special handing of html above
    });
});
```

This will allow you to maintain separation of code and only add the event listener if the the HTML is on the page.
Here is a link to a great post about using custom jQuery events: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-custom-events/